# JBoss 7 + Infinispan and Transactions

Tags: infinispan

I am using JBoss As 7.1.1 Final.
I have configured a replicated cache with transaction mode 'FULL_XA'.

I am using the cache as an in memory data base.The entries in the cache are manipulated(add/update/delete) by the application.
I am facing a scenario where a JTA transaction rollback does not revert the earlier addition of an entry in the cache.
Infinispan documentation specifies a transaction manager to be configured for the cache. I believe that on a JBoss application server, infinispan should automatically be able to choose the correct transaction manager.Moreover, the infinispan 1.2 XSD do not provide any details on how should we configure a transaction manager for the cache.
Do we really need to configure a transaction manager here ?
If not, what could be a probable cause of cache addition not being rolled back after transaction rollback.

Does infinispan provide the ability to remove previously added entry in the cache once the corresponding transaction is rolled back ?
This is essentially the same Atomicity guarantees provided by a persistent datastore such as RDBMS.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same question (and answer) on the Infinispan forums: https://community.jboss.org/message/778149#778149

Actually Infinispan doesn't write anything to the cache until the transaction is committed, so there's nothing to roll back - provided that the cache really is transactional, the default is not.

You can enable transactions via the `transactionMode` attribute of the [`transaction` element](http://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/5.1/configdocs/urn_infinispan_config_5.1/complexType/configuration.transaction.html). There's an attribute for customizing the transaction manager lookup as well (`transactionManagerLookupClass`), but as you guessed the default should work with AS7.